# C#: execute script from code behind with data asignment

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to refer to data using javascript from code behind with the following code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "************ some code ******** <h1>${data.features[0].properties.BLOCK}</h1></script>");
```

this part `${data.features[0].properties.BLOCK}` is not excecuted.

how can i write it?

Comment: `data.features[0].properties.BLOCK ` this cannot be refered from code behinde

Comment: data is a variable declared inside the script

Comment: Then refer to it in the script.  If it's not that simple then your question is not clear.

Comment: Change RegisterStartupScript to RegisterClientScriptBlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a placeholder in your template string (`${data.features[0].properties.BLOCK}`) without the use back-ticks. 
Additionaly, as pointed out by @Gauravsa, the script should be registered using `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, as it's an snippet, not `js` file.